# Why my first android MainActivity class extends ActionBarActivity instead of Activity?

Tags: android, myeclipse

I am trying to print hello world in my first android programs, via MyEclipse.
I created a project and start following online tutorials, where everywhere activity class extends Activity while my activity extends ActionBarActivity class, as I am new to this I am confused to proceed and failed to print hello world.

Normal tutorials code have -:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

My project activity class start with.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

please suggest me where to proceed for hello world outcome

Comment: ActionBarActivity backports some new feautures to older android versions. If you don't need it, you can extend activity.

Comment: See [Why does my Activity extend ActionBarActivity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392384/why-does-my-activity-extend-actionbaractivity) and [Difference Between Activity & ActionbarActivity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23089547/difference-between-activity-actionbaractivity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the type of `Activity` you choose when creating a new project via the wizard (`File>New>Android Application Project`). If you choose `Empty Activity` at the `Create Activity` page, you should get a starting point similar to the tutorials.