# Android ActionBar setCustomView NullPointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

I am using android API 15 and am trying to set a simple CustomView for the ActionBar and for some reason I am getting a NullPointer Exception this is my activity the exception is happening on         **actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.localview_actionbar);**

```
public class LocalView extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.local_view);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.localview_actionbar);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //  getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.local_view, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id== R.id.action_edit)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Popup Edit box",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

This is the error message

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.exoler.LocalView.onCreate(LocalView.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:1981)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and the simple custom View: localview_actionbar.xml is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<EditText
android:id="@+id/searchfield"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:text="Text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see it is a simple SearchField . Oh and I have also tried deleting the **onCreateOptionsMenu** and **onOptionsItemSelected** methods and still get the Error any suggestions would be great. I have searched around here for answers and have found none.

Comment: can you tell us the theme you used  inside your android manifest ?

Comment: Yes the Theme is style Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Comment: Better to learn this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392384/why-does-my-activity-extend-actionbaractivity

Comment: Are you using AppCompat v21. because there are lots of changes in appcompat library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
public class LocalView extends Activity
```

to

```
public class LocalView extends ActionBarActivity
```

and also do like

```
ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot the ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar(); worked , I appreciate it.